# Java constructor issue

Tags: java, constructor

I can not figure out why this code:

```
class HelloWorld
{
    HelloWorld()
    {
        System.out.println("1 cnstr ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HelloWorld a = new HelloWorld();
    }


    {
        System.out.println("2 cnstr ");
    }
}
```

gives me the output:

```
2 cnstr
1 cnstr
```

Why does line `System.out.println("2 cnstr ");` work? What kind of block is it? I used `jdb` and found that `JVM` starts block with this line in `HelloWorld()` constructor before any line in it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can also use `static { }` to initialize `static` variables which are declared outside constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
        System.out.println("2 cnstr ");
    }
```

Its an **Instance Initialization block**. It is run before constructor of the class is executed.

From [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html):

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors.

Answer (score 5):

It's an instance initializer block, which gets executed before each constructor.

Comment: Initialization block of the constructor or of the whole class?

Comment: Such a block is used in every constructor of that class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html